# gdal/ogr python adding new feature into an existing PostGIS table

Tags: python, postgis, gdal, ogr

I am trying to add data into [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) via [gdal/ogr](https://gdal.org/) in Python.

If I use `OGRDataSource.CreateLayer("test")` to create the layer, then I can add a new feature successfully.

However, when tables are already defined in the database, if I use `OGRDataSource.GetLayer(table_name)` to get the layer and then try to add/edit feature, it does not work.

I found differences after running `OGRLayer.TestCapabilities()` on both layers. If layer is referenced by `CreateLayer()`,  the capabilities `SequentialWrite` and `RandomWrite` are both **True**. If an existing layer is referenced using `GetLayer()`, those two capabilities are **False**. I think this explains why adding a feature fails.

But how can I enable them or what is a better way to insert a new record (no geometry) into PostGIS using Python?

```
**# The user is the owner of this database**.
conn_str = "PG: host=%s dbname=%s user=%s password=%s" %('localhost', 'CEdB', 'test', 'test')
conn = ogr.Open(conn_str)

def this_create_layer_and_add_feature_OK():
    # here we create test_made table
    layer = conn.CreateLayer('test_made', None, ogr.wkbUnknown, ['OVERWRITE=YES'])
    # add new fields
    err_code = layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('object_id', ogr.OFTInteger))
    field_def = ogr.FieldDefn('name', ogr.OFTString)
    field_def.SetWidth(50)
    err_code = layer.CreateField(field_def)
    feature = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())
    feature.SetField('object_id', 1)
    feature.SetField('name', 'testing')
    layer.StartTransaction()
    err_code = layer.CreateFeature(feature)
    feature = None
    layer.CommitTransaction()


def this_not_create_feature_in_table():
    # test_table is a predefined table, with 2 columns, no geometry!
    lyr = conn.GetLayer("test")
    new_feature = ogr.Feature(lyr.GetLayerDefn())
    new_feature.SetField("object_id", 1)
    new_feature.SetField("name", 'testing')
    lyr.StartTransaction()
    if lyr.CreateFeature(new_feature) == ogr.OGRERR_NONE:
        new_feature = None
        err_code = lyr.CommitTransaction()
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Other posts (e.g. https://gist.github.com/patmisch/2650602) refer to psycopg2 (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial). Maybe this is the way? I'll investigate

Comment: Yes.I have to switch to psycopg2 for updating/inserting.

Comment: Even you can use SqlAlchemy for more abstraction. but I also recommend Psycopg2. it is the most popular python driver for PostgreSQL. 
make sure to add your code in exception blocks. Refer this https://pynative.com/python-postgresql-tutorial/ guide for all the DB operations through Python.